# Ubuntu 22.10 External monitor connection issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, xrandr, monitors

I have recently install 22.10 Ubuntu OS and I lost external monitor connectivity. I have tried few things but stuck.

OS: Ubuntu 22.10

**xrandr**:

```
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0xa7
    Timestamp:  5598
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      4 5 6 7
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    dithering depth: auto 
        supported: auto, 6 bpc, 8 bpc
    dithering mode: auto 
        supported: auto, off, static 2x2, dynamic 2x2, temporal
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    color vibrance: 150 
        range: (0, 200)
    vibrant hue: 90 
        range: (0, 180)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: auto, off, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CONNECTOR_ID: 101 
        supported: 101
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
```

I turn off *wayland* setting and turn on *X11* And whenever I go to *Settings > About* my laptop freeze.

Additionally, I don't see display layout to setup monitor. I have Dell Dock and tried with DP1 and HDMI cables but didn't work.

[image]

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried multiple tricks to find a solution inside the Linux system. Afterwards, I have tried to find a solution for the Dock driver connector to display my external monitor. And it works, here what I have done:

- Download external Nvidia drivers as mentioned by kepler-22. https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx
- Go to terminal and run downloaded file from above link: `sudo ./filename.run` In my case, I did `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.85.05.run`
- Download Ubuntu drivers for Dell Dock from https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu
- Open downloaded folder. It has a .run file. In my case, `sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.6.1-59.184.run`
- sudo reboot
- Additionally, I had to install `sudo apt-get install evdi-dkms`
- Afterwards, I got an external display (LG), Dell Dock with MSI laptop.